# If else in Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i am a noob to jquery and i want to know how to make use of if else for the following:

on the server side there is a  **if** for number of rows is equal to 0 and **else** some JSON part.

```
$age= mysql_query("SELECT title FROM parent WHERE id ='$name'");
$age_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($age);   
  if ($age_num_rows==0) 
  {
   echo "true";  
  }
  else
  {
$sql ="SELECT * FROM parentid WHERE id = '$name'"; //$name is value from html      
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
$abc_output = array('title' => $row['title'],'age' => $row['age']);
     }
echo json_encode($abc_output);
  }
```

Now coming to Jquery part :

If the above PHP code go to **if** part then i want to display an alert box or if it goes to **else** part it needs to insert some values into the forms. 
Here is something i tried but it did not work.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){  
      $("#button1").click(function(){
        $.getJSON('script_1.php',function(data){
            if (data=='true') {
                 alert ('hello')
            }
            else {
                $.post('script_1.php', 
                    { id: $('input[name="id"]', '#myForm').val() }, 
                    function(json) { 
                        $("input[name='title']").val(json.title);
                        $("input[name='age']").val(json.age); 
                    }, 
                    "json");  
            }
      });
  });
```

**Edited**:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){  
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $.post(
        'script.php',
        { id: $('input[name="id"]', '#myForm').val() },
        function(json) { 
            var data = JSON.parse(json);
            if (data.length === 0){
             alert('no data');   
            }
            else{
            $("input[name='title']").val(json.title);
                    $("input[name='age']").val(json.age); 

            }},
        "json"
    );
});
});
```

PHP side

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']); 
$sql ="SELECT * FROM parentid WHERE id = '$name'";       
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($row) {
$row=  array('title' => $row['title'],'age' => $row['age']);
echo json_encode($row);
} else {
echo json_encode(array());
}
```

Comment: When you say it didn't work, what did you see?

Comment: "If else loop"? What you mean is known as a condition, not a loop… Also you don't return JSON-data from within the `if($age_num_rows==0)` – the echo should read: `json_encode(true);`

Comment: I think `data == 'yes'` should be `data == 'true'` looking at your PHP code. Aside from that, what 'didn't work'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be a few problems:

1. You are treating the data returned from `getJSON` as if it is plain
   text
2. The php that you are calling from javascript does not always
   return json
3. You are doing 2 ajax requests; `getJSON` and `post` where you only need one: The first call to `getJSON` without any data will never reach the `else` condition

By the way, where does `$name` come from in your php script? For your second ajax call to work, it needs to be something like `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'])` or `(int) $_POST['id']` if it is an integer.

**Edit:** I think it would be easiest to get rid of the `.post` and just use the first ajax call. So you will need to change:

```
$.getJSON('script_1.php',function(data){
```

to something like:

```
$.getJSON('script_1.php?id=' + $('input[name="id"]').val(), function(data) {
```

and in your php you need to use something like:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

Comment: thankss the third point you said is the problem..how can i achieve the above using 1 ajax request ...a small code snippet will be highly appreciated..

Comment: for the $name it comes from html ...i did not include the above syntax which u mentioned in the code here ,but it is actually present in the original php..

Comment: hey thanks a lot for your time..based on your suggestions i edited the code ..it is in the edited section above..still it does not go to the else part..is it code wrong??

Comment: @John You still have problems 1. and 2. to deal with, also see Stephen Searles's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the JSON before you can use it like that. Modern browsers will have built in support for `JSON.parse(yourJSON)`, but to account for those that don't, you should use [Douglas Crockford's JavaScript JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). Including it will provide `JSON.parse()` if the browser doesn't have it already.

For the if-else stuff you're doing in the PHP, the common practice is to echo out an empty JSON object or array, so you don't have to test for things like no rows on the server side. You could do something as simple as this, later accounting for your database column names:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row) {
  echo json_encode($row);
} else {
  echo json_encode(array());
}
```

Back in the JavaScript, you could then do something like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
if (data.length === 0) {
  alert('no data');
} else {
  $("input[name='title']").val(data.title);
  $("input[name='age']").val(data.age);
}
```

jeroen is right though, you only need to use one AJAX call.

Comment: Hey Charles ...i have made the edits as you suggested and still the code does not seem to work...i included the edited part above can you please let me know if there is anything wrong in the code above?

Comment: The only thing standing out to me is that it still won't work in some browsers. See the very beginning of my answer about including Crockford's code.

Comment: firbug throws up this error JSON.parse: unexpected end of data
[Break On This Error] var data = JSON.parse(json);

Comment: Yeah, well it would on an older browser. That error, though, means there's a problem with your JSON. I have to run, but setting a breakpoint and looking at that is where to start.